# OpenCV - Find skewed rectangle

Tags: image-processing, opencv

I want to draw a "bounding box" around a skewed rectangle. I thought I could use the cvMinAreaRect2() function but it only handles the rotation, see this image:

[image]

Is there any function to solve this?
If not, any ideas how to implement it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compute both MinAreaRect and ConvexHull. Then, for each of the four points found by MinAreaRect, find the corresponding nearest point in the convex hull.